# Select from datatable with where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, datatable

I am trying to select a few rows from a datatable. I am selecting two of the columns and how can I use a where clause in the below statement?

```
cars = new Head
{
    heading = (string)dr["head"],
    subHeads = dt.Select(r => new SubHead
    {                               // how to use a where clause here?
        subHeading = (string)r["subhead"],
        cars = dt.Select(r2 => new Cars
        {                           // how to use a where clause here?
            name = (string)r2["name"],
            quantity = (string)r2["qty"],
        }).ToList()
     }).ToList()
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use,

```
dt.where(e => {check something}).Select({select code here})
```

Do this on both the places. Hope this helps.

Comment: How to select a particular column? I want to select "subhead" column alone for variable subHeads. I added ".Select(c => c.Field<string>("subhead"))"  at line 4  but it throws error "The best overloaded method match for 'string.this[int]' has some invalid arguments" at line 6. Please help.

Comment: cars = new Head
{
    heading = (string)dr["head"],
    subHeads = dt.Select(c => c.Field<string>("subhead")).Select(r => new SubHead
    {                               // how to use a where clause here?
        subHeading = (string)r["subhead"],
        cars = dt.Select(r2 => new Cars
        {                           // how to use a where clause here?
            name = (string)r2["name"],
            quantity = (string)r2["qty"],
        }).ToList()
     }).ToList()
 };

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the Where before you select. Example:

```
// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
FillDataSet(ds);

var contacts = ds.Tables["Contact"].AsEnumerable();
var orders = ds.Tables["SalesOrderHeader"].AsEnumerable();

var query =
    contacts.SelectMany(
        contact => orders.Where(order =>
            (contact.Field<Int32>("ContactID") == order.Field<Int32>("ContactID"))
                && order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue") < 500.00M)
            .Select(order => new
            {
                ContactID = contact.Field<int>("ContactID"),
                LastName = contact.Field<string>("LastName"),
                FirstName = contact.Field<string>("FirstName"),
                OrderID = order.Field<int>("SalesOrderID"),
                Total = order.Field<decimal>("TotalDue")
            }));

foreach (var smallOrder in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Contact ID: {0} Name: {1}, {2} Order ID: {3} Total Due: ${4} ",
        smallOrder.ContactID, smallOrder.LastName, smallOrder.FirstName,
        smallOrder.OrderID, smallOrder.Total);
}
```

taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).